# How can I tell if a Dialog is being Stopped by it closing or by the application being minimized?

Tags: android, android-dialog, android-lifecycle

I implement a dialog that should update its calling activity when it is closed. However, I've found that it is updating the activity when the entire application is minimized, which is not acceptable for my purposes.

The update to the activity occurs in the dialog's `onStop()` method, which is called either when the dialog is closed or the application itself is stopped. How can I handle things differently based on whether the dialog was closed or the application itself was stopped?  Thanks!

For some more context, here is the piece of my dialog's `onStop()`, which resumes the timer of the underlying activity. I don't want the timer resumed if the user is leaving the app.

```
if (activity instanceof QuizActivity) {
            if( ((QuizActivity) activity).getTimer() == null) {
                ((QuizActivity) activity).resumeTimer();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I just solved this. My Dialog's `onStop()` was being called manually from my Activity's `onStop()`. So I put a call to my `pauseTimer()` method *after* calling the dialog's `onStop()` in the activity's `onStop()`. Effectively, the dialog is resuming the timer and then the activity is immediately pausing it again as part of its `onStop()` method. It doesn't feel very clean, but hopefully it at least holds together.